# jquerytools tooltip to target the tooltip into a special div instead of a position relative to trigger's

Tags: jquery, tooltip, slideshow, jquery-tools

I'm using [**jquerytools tooltip**](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/).

The tooltip will come at a position ***relative*** to its trigger (the element that brings the tooltip).

I know that it's controllable using the `position` and `offset` options like this:

```
$('#trigger').tooltip({effect: 'slide', offset: [63, -172]});
```

, but it's still ***relative to the trigger***.

**Anyway, the question is how should the tooltip come into a special `div`** like `<div id="target"></div>`?

I have even tried `$('#trigger').tooltip(effect: 'slide', target: '#target')` but no difference.

It can be somehow called a slideshow, but the difference is that when none of the slide's thumbnails is hovered, nothing should be shown, and the default background image will be visible. So I've decided to use this way. (So shouldn't also have a behavior to show each slide after some time).

---

**UPDATE:**

Because of the problem, I used the solution below that is really ugly, but *it works*!

```
$("#slide1").tooltip({ effect: 'slide', offset: [-10, -213]});
$("#slide2").tooltip({ effect: 'slide', offset: [-10, -108]});
$("#slide3").tooltip({ effect: 'slide', offset: [-10, -3]});
$("#slide4").tooltip({ effect: 'slide', offset: [-10, 102]});
$("#slide5").tooltip({ effect: 'slide', offset: [-10, 207]});
```

In fact, using this method, all the tooltips will be on top of a special div and they will have the same x, y. *(They also have the same **height**, **width** as well)*

---

Still looking for a more clear solution.

Comment: I don't know why but someone has voted to close the question. I have no problem with closing my question or even voting it down! But it'd be very better to tell me the reason and I'd of course edit it to be as it should be! Thank you

Comment: I think you need to calculate the tooltip targets position in the page, the position of the element you want the tooltip to show near and then use that difference in the offset you have now.

Comment: And that's exactly what I had done in the update. But it looks a really really _ugly_ way. It's also very static, manual and not convenience.

Comment: I mean calculate dynamically.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var target_top = $('#target').position().top;
var anchor_top = $('#trigger').position().top;
var final_position = anchor_top - target_top;
$('#trigger').tooltip({effect: 'slide', offset: [63, final_position]});
```

Try this for the top/y coordinate. I did not test this, you can post some html or a link if you want more exact answer.